# How can I apply dropout per row of a 2d tensor in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, torch, dropout

I have a (relatively sparse) 2d tensor `U` of shape `(B, I)` of 1s and 0s. Each row represents a user and each column an item where the cell is 1 if the user has interacted with said item and 0 if not.

I want to apply dropout (or a similar tensor operation to it) so that, at random, `p%` of the 1s **in each row** (i.e. per user) are set to 0.

How can I go about doing that efficiently without a for-loop along the `B` dimension (where I would just use pytorch's dropout on the row 1d tensors, after accounting for the 0s)?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to build the network out manually? One way to do this would be to create a boolean array (same size of your weights) each run. Then multiply that with the weight before using it.

```
dropout = torch.randint(2, (10,))
weights = torch.randn(10)
dr_wt = dropout * weights
```

#### Edit

you can create a array with 10% 1s rest 0s. then shuffle it every run to multiply with the weights.

```
a = np.zeros(10)
a[0] = 1
np.random.shuffle(a)
a = torch.as_tensor(a)
```

Comment: What I am interested in is how do I create that boolean array so that 10% of 1s in each row get a False value and the rest 90% of 1s get a True value (it doesn't matter what value the 0s have because they are already zero).

Comment: Does the above edit work for your case?

Comment: Not really because I would still need to apply it for every row separately in a loop which would be too slow.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you say you want a p% of 1s to turn to 0s per row, then row 0 might have 10 1s and row 1 might have 100. When you apply dropout on average, only one of the 1s gets affected by the dropout mask, while about 10 get affected in the second row.

```
def dropout(input: Tensor, p: float = 0.5):
    mask = torch.rand_like(input) > p # creates a bool tensor
    return input * mask
```

I don't know how you would be able to guarantee that exactly 10% get nulled without using some sort of row-based sampling of nonzero indices, which in turn requires a for loop.